# Can I use this Expo library in my React Native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, barcode-scanner

I'm working on a React Native app and have never used Expo before. [This library](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/) called `Expo Barcode Scanner` is installed with `expo install expo-barcode-scanner`. Can I use this in my React Native project if I didn't build it with Expo?

Comment: yes, you can install expo modules

Answer (score 2):

yes you can! you can follow [this guide for installing Expo module support in your app](https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/) and then [follow the installation instructions on the BarCodeScanner docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/bar-code-scanner/).